# trouble with ServiceProvider in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Being new to Laravel, I followed *Repositories Simplified* on Laracasts and created a `BackendServiceProvider` class.

Now, when I want to do

```
php artisan generate:controller TestController
```

I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class '_testic\repos\BackendServiceProvider' not found in
/vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
on line 158
```

**What did go wrong? How can I solve it?**

What I did so far:

1. put my service-provider into `config/app.php`
2. then added it to `composer.json` inside `psr-0`:

   ```
   {
   "name": "laravel/laravel",
   "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
   "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
   "license": "MIT",
   "require": {
       "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
   },
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "app/commands",
           "app/controllers",
           "app/models",
           "app/database/migrations",
           "app/database/seeds",
           "app/tests/TestCase.php"
       ]
   },
   "psr-0": {
           "_testic": "app/"  // <----- my entry
       },
   "scripts": { ...
   ```
3. ran `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The psr-0 goes inside autoload. Just next to classmap.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "_testic": "app/"  // <----- my entry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually those kind of problems are from a malformation in namespaces, file name or directory structure.

You defined a PSR-0 namespacing as:

```
"_testic": "app/" --> which means 'my _testic namespace is stored in the folder app/'
```

And, according to the error message, you namespaced your file as

```
_testic\repos\BackendServiceProvider
```

So I have to assume that you will use that particular file in your other files as:

```
use _testic\repos\BackendServiceProvider;
```

Which also means that you MUST have your `BackendServiceProvider.php` file in the folder

```
/whateverRootFoldersYouMayHave/app/_testic/repos/BackendServiceProvider.php
```

If this is not your folder structure, you will receive this error.

Note that in PSR-0 the whole folder structure must be equal the one you defined as your root namespace.